# Displaying linked text in a groovy template GSP

Tags: java, groovy, gsp

I have a code that should display data on the page of the model

```
<% if (patients) { %>
    <% patients.each { %>
    <tr>
        <td>${ ui.format(it.status) }</td>
        <td align="center">
        <% def linkClaim="patientView.page?patientId=' + ${patientId}+ '&claimUuid=" + ${it.uuid} %>
        <button onclick="location.href='${linkClaim}'" type="button">Details</button>
    </td>
    </tr>
<% } %>
```

Data from the model:

- patients
- patientId

Error:

`groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: SimpleTemplateScript171.$()`

Comment: `${it.uuid}`->`it.uuid`

Comment: Like daggett says use it.uuid when you are out of string closure. If in string closure you need to use $something if it's not nested, if nested you need ${something.like.this}.